# How to render LaTeX in an Android program?

Tags: tex-core, programming, distributions, rendering, android

Recently I'm writing a calc program, on android. As a frequent LaTeX user, it comes to be compelling to use LaTeX rendering in displaying the inputs and outputs.

Is there any possibilities to use a minimal/basic TeX distribution to render simple equations including sin/cos/tan, fractions etc.?

I've heard of BasicTeX but it seems far too huge, and it may not work on android system, I suppose?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate---it's only asking to typeset equations that, while an important draw of TeX systems, is only a portion of the picture.  As for the Q, instead of looking for a minimal TeX distribution, I would take a look at MathJax for this particular case.  Hop on over to [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) for some examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Android software is written in Java, you may try something like [JLaTeXMath](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/), which is a Java library that renders LaTeX equations.